# Matching two lists of data with different conventions

Tags: algorithms, data

I have two lists of data, A and B. These lists are themselves aggregated from multiple sources, and contain typos, abbreviations not found in the other, and also lack a 1-1 mapping, but will never have a value in A that maps to two values in B and vice-versa.

Right now, we're doing a naive (string comparison) match to create a map between the two lists. That has about 80% accuracy. I'd like to get that accuracy to at least 90% (95% would be incredible).

Are there any software tools that can be used for something like this? I'd like some sort of tool that could traverse both lists and suggest matches.

**Update from comments:**

Right now, we only produce a hit if `A[x] == B[y]`. That gives us matches for 80% of the data in the data sets (which contain roughly fifty thousand rows each). What I'd like to do is find a tool or develop one based on an algorithm that will allow me to suggest a match for two values that are likely to have the same meaning, e.g. `KING ROAD` and `KG RD`. These potential matches would then be provided to a human to review and approve or ignore. Generally, I'd use something like Levenshtein, but this is somewhat parametrized data (think addresses) and I don't know how to apply something like Levenshtein to structured data.

Comment: can you please show us some string example?

Comment: If you ask for tools, your are on the wrong site. Algorithms and suggestions: of course, try to find the string/strings with the smallest edit-distance (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance), or use Soundex (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex)

Comment: You must first define your "match" criteria accurately. I second @Doc Brown in his recommendations.

Comment: Because of the nature of the data, I don't know if I am allowed to provide specific examples, however one would be an entry in list `A` being `KING ROAD` while a second in list `B` being `KG RD`.

Comment: How do you define accuracy?  Hits?  Isn't that dependent upon the data and not on the algorithm?

Comment: Right now, accuracy is defined as `A[x] == B[y]`. I'd like to find an algorithm that will allow me to see approximate hits so that those can be reviewed by a human to see if they are actual hits. For reference, each data set has about fifty thousand values.

Comment: Do the items in these lists have any related data *other than* the single data point you're comparing?

Comment: @JimmyHoffa Yes, they share a year and another related field, which I can probably compare with Levenshtein because it appears to only be troubled with spelling mistakes.

Comment: @JonathanRich then you may have historical evidence of "KG RD", 2009, Pennsylvania from A, and now have "King Road", 2009, Pennsylvania, and be able to use that historical KG RD trusted from A to have a match in B, with the similarity with the current "King Road"s other elements in A and have that trip it over to saying they're the same. That's based on edit distance to begin with though, and the year can give you a conclusive exclusion where edit distance might otherwise say they're close enough.

Comment: So you're suggesting a trained algorithm?

Comment: For addresses you could establish a set of rules how to unify certain fields of the address. In the "street", it makes sense to replace "RD" by "road" like you've mentioned. Other unification examples: &=and Comp=Company. Convert all characters to lowercase and eliminate/replace foreign characters á=a ä=ae ... In the "first name" you could sort multiple names alphabetically. Fields like postcode or phonenumbers are typically more meaningful than others. You could estimate a fuzzy similarity measure and define a threshold for "equal" candidates